# Rails And Bootsrap-table Usage - JSON Table Not Loading On Initial Visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am trying to get my data to display into a table with the ability to show selected columns.  I think the twitter-bootstrap can do what I need, but it doesn't have much documentation or full on code examples I can follow very easily with being newer to rails / JSON.

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html

I can access my JSON data with /weights.json and it displays like the following:

```
{
          "id": 163,
      "weight": "111.0",
        "note": "test new",
     "user_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-01-07T01:43:29.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-01-07T01:43:29.000Z"
}
```

One thing to note is, my JSON does not look pretty.. It comes out in one line and hard to read.  Is it supposed to do this when you use a format.json in the controller?  Or is it supposed to be multi lined like the above?

My table:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="weights.json" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "weight" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "note" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "created_at", "Date" %></th>
      <th class="nopadding"></th>
      <th class="nopadding"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The documentation at this point just makes it sound like it will work?  No other info is needed?  Am I not calling the data-url properly?  Do I need to use the full URL?

How would I implement this with JS calls and to implement the showColumns and showToggle options?

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

Alright.. I have this working!  However, when I load the index page / action.. It doesn't load the table the first time.  Any thoughts?  I have to refresh the page in order for the table to load the table with the JSON data.  Below I will post all my code.

I am now stuck on how do I edit or delete the entry?  I at first put the <% link_to %> in the .JS file.. But after thinking about it.. that won't work within the JS.

So how do I send an edit or delete through my button?

(FYI, I have regenerated my scaffold, so there are new fields compared to the top post)

application.js:

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return 
[        '<a class="edit ml10 btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

function operateFormatter2(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="remove ml10 btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

window.operateEvents = {
    'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click remove icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    }
};
```

index.html.erb:

```
    <div id="custom-toolbar">
      <%= link_to new_weight_tracker_path, :class => "btn btn-default", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#addMeasurement", 'aria-label' => "Add New Measurement" do %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><% end %>
</div>
<table id="table-pagination" data-toggle="table" data-url="/weight_trackers.json" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#custom-toolbar" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-height="600" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="created_at" data-show-export="true" data-sort-order="desc" data-export-types="['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'excel']" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="weight" data-sortable="true" data-align="right">Weight:</th>
      <th data-field="waist" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Waist:</th>
      <th data-field="wrist" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Wrist:</th>
      <th data-field="hip" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Hip:</th>
      <th data-field="forearm" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Forearm:</th>
      <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="left">Note:</th>
      <th data-field="created_at" data-sortable="true" data-align="right">Date:</th>
      <th class="nopadding" data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents" data-align="center" data-valign="center" data-halign="center"></th>
      <th class="nopadding" data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter2" data-events="operateEvents" data-align="center" data-valign="center" data-halign="center"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

weight_trackers_controller.rb:

```
  def index
  @weight_trackers = WeightTracker.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  @weight_tracker = WeightTracker.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @weight_trackers }
    format.xml { render :xml => @weight_trackers.to_xml }
  end
end
def new
  @weight_tracker = WeightTracker.new
  respond_with(@weight_tracker)
end
```

So again, my question is.. how do I make the buttons for edit / delete columns, call the edit method / page or the delete option.

***Update 2***

I have edit and delete working!  See the below application.js code:

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="edit ml10 btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

function operateFormatter2(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="remove ml10 btn btn-default" data-method="delete" href="/weight_trackers/' + row.id + '" title="Delete">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

window.operateEvents = {
    'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
        document.location.href='/weight_trackers/' + row.id + '/edit'

        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('Are you sure you want to delete entry for ' + row.created_at);
        document.location.href='/weight_trackers'
        console.log(value, row, index);
    }
};
```

This does it.. However now I need to work on having the edit open a modal.

I am still having one pretty big issue though.  The table will not load on initial page open.  Any ideas on how I can get it to load the JSon data without having to reload / F5 the page?

Comment: Anybody? Any thoughts on loading the JSON without having to refresh the page?

Comment: I guess to better put it.. How would I go about preloading / bootstrapping the JSON data on page load?

Answer (score 3):

edited the last few lines in the bootstrap-table.js file to read:

```
    // BOOTSTRAP TABLE INIT
    // =======================

    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
        $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
    });
```

rails 4.2.6, turbolinks 5.0.1, bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3

seems to be working fine.

Comment: and actually I added this to assets/javasctripts in its own file, so as not to edit the vendor library directly and allow for easy updating.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the bootstrap table loading only after refreshing the page.

A workaround was to edit the following line in bootstrap-table.js

```
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

to

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In my case though, that created a "duplicate" table controls (f.e. pagination or search box) generation when navigating using back and forward buttons.

UPDATE:

Gave up and used this post with disabling turbolinks on specific page (add data-turbolinks="false" to body tag) to make it work correctly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455004