# Bootstrap table options: filter and search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using bootstrap tables on several pages of my app (on Rails 6) and the [tables load correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PP9y.png).

However, I want to enable the column sorting and search feature and these only appear when I refresh the page: [with fixed-table-toolbar displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqzID.png)

Some of my **application.js**:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery");
require("bootstrap");
require("chartkick");
require("chart.js");

import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js";
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-fr-FR.js';
```

Which is loaded in **application.html.erb** with `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

(I also tried to put the bootstrap-tables import in another pack file and import it separately.)

If I try to import bootstrap-table in a script at the bottom of my **application.html.erb** to see I will get these error messages, most likely because Jquery hasn't been loaded yet:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'BootstrapTable' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'BootstrapTable' of undefined
    at VM1101 bootstrap-table.min.js:10
    at VM1101 bootstrap-table.min.js:10
    at VM1101 bootstrap-table.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-table.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-table.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-table.min.js:10
bootstrap-table-fr-FR.js:678 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at VM1103 bootstrap-table-fr-FR.js:678
    at VM1103 bootstrap-table-fr-FR.js:4
```

I am running out of ideas, after having moved my import files and script all around so I would be eternally grateful if someone already had the same issue and could share his/her thoughts!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to see more of your code to be sure, but I'm guessing the issue is that `bootstrap-table` is using some form of `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, which only fires on a full page load/reload. When you navigate with Turbolinks enabled, it isn't an actual page load, and the `ready` event isn't fired.

You likely need to add a secondary event listener for the `turbolinks:load` event, which is what fires when a new page is loaded via Turbolinks. Something like:

```
// put this in your application.js or another file AFTER bootstrap-table
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883268/rails-and-bootsrap-table-usage-json-table-not-loading-on-initial-visit) for more information.

Comment: Problem is exactly that and I couldn't find how to make it wait for turbolinks to load! I tried this yesterday but I must have put it in a bad place cause it kept telling me "bootstrapTable isn't a function" but today works like a charm! Thanks so much!

Comment: So glad it helped! If it worked and you could accept the answer for others to find, I'd appreciate it. Thanks and good luck!